# Is there a word for the landscape you see from the top of a mountain?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a word for the landscape you see from the top of a mountain? Or is there a phrase? The only word or phrase I can think of is "stretching view of a landscape". I am wondering if there's a better phrase or word for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [panorama](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/panorama) fits nicely

> An unobstructed or complete view of an area in every direction.

The example at the bottom of the linked definition even applies directly to your case

> We admired the breathtaking *panorama* from the top of the mountain.